# Team Combinatorics, Q14 from a mock competition (POGIME) on AoPS

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> There are two teams of 10 people each, Team  and Team . For some number  with
> 1 ≤  ≤ 9, Team  chooses some  people in its team and kicks them out of the team. Then, for some  with 0 ≤  ≤ , Team  chooses  of its people to replace with  of the  people kicked out from Team . After these changes, there are  distinct possible combinations of teams. Find the remainder when  is divided by 1000.

This was the original problem, however I could not find a way to simplify this to make the solution not involve a large amount of bashing.

My attempt was to say that this problem is equivalent to: Team B kicks 0-9 (n) members, then takes the same amount from team A, while team A then kicks out anywhere from 0 to 9-n members from their current 10-n members. Then subtract the case where both team A and B kicks 0 members. Summing the above from n=0 to n=9 gives

$$\sum_{n=0}^9 {10 \choose n}^2 \left(2^{10-n}-1 \right)-1=7912696$$

There was another thread on AoPS [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2768068p24254420), which gives the following alternative forms:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{9}\binom{10}{n} \binom{n+10}{n}$$

$$\sum_{a+2b=10}\binom{10}{a,b,b}3^a2^b - {20 \choose 10}$$

I wonder if there is a more direct way (a way that involves less computations) to find this.

Comment: Shouldn't team B be only kicking out $m$ members, not $n$?

Comment: Yes, but m and n are just placeholders so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{10}{n} $ ways for players to be ejected from Team A and then there are $\binom{10+n}{10} $ ways for Team B to be chosen. Hence we require$$\sum_{n=1}^{9}\binom{10}{n} \binom{10+n}{n}.$$

The left hand binomial factors can be calculated easily by successive multiplying by $\frac{9}{2},\frac{8}{3},....$ and also using symmetry. We obtain $$10,45,120,210,252,210,120,45,10$$

The right hand binomial factors can be calculated easily by successive multiplying by $\frac{12}{2},\frac{13}{3},....$.
Modulo $1000$ we obtain $$11,66,286,1,3,8,448,758,378.$$
Adding symmetrically placed numbers modulo $200$ or $100$ (depending upon the LH binomial factor) simplifies the calculation to $$10\times89+45\times24+120\times 34+210\times 9+252\times3.$$

Multiplying and adding modulo $1000$ then gives your answer of $696$.